# How to add and remove from array in VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need to add and remove elements from the end of an array in VB.

In Java, if I have two methods (the one that adds an element to an array and the one that removes an element from an array) I would complete this by creating a static global variable.  Each time I call the add method, I would just insert and then add one to the location static variable, and then if I would need to delete something I would get that variable and then subtract one from it.  This is how I would add an element to the end of the array and remove the last element in the array.  Can you go about this problem in the same exact manner in VB?  I'm not very familiar with VB so the syntax is throwing me off.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if I understand that right, you should use a stack , this is also true for Java. In VBA you can create one by using this -> Set stack = CreateObject("System.Collections.Stack") where stack is a variable of the type object.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx#Anchor_10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not built-in or direct way to do this with arrays, unless you can use a `Collection` object.

```
Public Sub TestArr()
    Dim list As New Collection

    list.Add "John"
    list.Add "Mary"
    list.Add "Bob"

    list.Remove 1
End Sub
```

With arrays you can `ReDim` them using the `Preserve` keyword to keep existing data.

```
Public Sub TestArr()
    Dim list() As Variant
    'Creates a dynamic list of 10 items
    ReDim list(1 To 10)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        list(i) = "Item" & CStr(i)
    Next i

    'Append to the end of an array
    AppendToArray list, "NotAnItem"

    'Remove the 5th element
    RemoveFromArray list, 5
End Sub

Public Sub AppendToArray(ByRef list() As Variant, ByVal item As Variant)
    Dim n As Long
    n = UBound(list)
    ' Make Room
    ReDim Preserve list(1 To n + 1)
    ' Assign new value
    list(n + 1) = item
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveFromArray(ByRef list() As Variant, ByVal index As Long)
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    n = UBound(list)
    ' Move last items down by one
    For i = index To n - 1
        list(i) = list(i + 1)
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve list(1 To n - 1)
End Sub
```